# How to exclude lines that has given columns?

Tags: text-processing, awk

There is an input file that has TAB delimited columns.

We need to remove the lines which has "NA" for the fourth AND the eleventh column.

**Question:** how can we do this in awk?

Comment: Please always include an example of your input and your desired output, it makes understanding your question much easier and greatly increases your chances of getting a useful answer. Do you want to remove lines that have `NA` on _both_ the 4th and the 11th field or on _either_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F"\t" '$4 != "NA" || $11 != "NA"' filename
```

Note, awk does not edit the file in-place. If you want to save the changes back to the file, then:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
awk -F"\t" '...' filename > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" filename
```

Answer (score 3):

You tell `awk` to print the lines that do not meet your criteria.

```
BEGIN { FS="\t" }
$4 != "NA" || $11 != "NA"
```

This is a reverse of boolean logic where `~a|~b == a&b`.